# AngularJS ngRoute - fetch additional data from template request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, wordpress

I am writing a portal on WordPress with AngularJS. I made some pages, that i can get via wp slug. This is how router looks like:

```
.when('/', {
    template: '?async=1>',
    controller: 'homeController',
    controllerAs: 'works',
})
.when('/works', {
    template: 'works/?async=1>',
    controller: 'worksController',
    controllerAs: 'works',
})
.when('/blog', {
    template: 'blog/?async=1>',
    controller: 'blogController',
    controllerAs: 'blog',
})

// etc
```

I use `async` GET parameter to indicate, wheter its normal get request from browser or template request from Angular.

Now the problem is, that i want to fetch some meta data when requesting the template like title, meta description and some others.

Maybe using some custom headers (how to fetch them this way)? Or is it possible to somehow intercept response, alter it and return html for rendering?

I know, that i could use hidden inputs, but it's not  kind of best-practice.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's not the best way, but i found a solution.

I used custom directive and on linking i just use injected service to spread those data where i need.

```
myApp.directive("metaData", ['metaService', function(metaService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            metaService.set({
                title : attrs.title,
                description: attrs.description
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

and the directive:

```
<meta-data data-title="The title" data-description="The description"></meta-data>
```